# Rocky Linux 9 can't mount share because CIFS is a dummy module

Tags: linux, kernel, cifs

I have tried to mount an SMB share using cifs with this command:
`sudo mount.cifs -o vers=3.0,uid=user,credentials=/home/user/credentials,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 //path/to/share /mnt/share`
And I got:

```
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
```

so I debugged it and when i ran `modinfo cifs` this is what returned:

```
filename: /lib/modules/5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.×86_64/extra/mlnx-ofa_kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
version: 2.31
license: Dual BSD/GPL
description: cifs dummy kernel module
author: Mohammad Kabat
rheiversion: 9.1
sreversion: 01E451882B55F354B7F130B
depends: mlx_compat
retpoline: Y
name: cifs
vermagic: 5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.×86_64 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
sig_id: PKCS#7
signer: Mellanox Technologies signing key
sig_key: BA:BO:F5:CD:23:24:A0
sig_hashalgo: sha256
```

I use `MLNX_OFED` on my system and it seems that the `Mellanox Kernel` is using a dummy module of cifs and by that is disabling the `CIFS` option. (As refered in the [MLNX_OFED v5.8-2.0.3.0 known issues](https://docs.nvidia.com/networking/display/MLNXOFEDv582030LTS/Known%20Issues)).
My question is if there's a way to work around it and renabling `CIFS` manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigating the issue, I have found that I am using `OFED-5.8-1.1.2.1` On `Rocky Linux 9.1` and it supports only up to `Rocky Linux 9.0`.
So, updating the `OFED` to `OFED-5.8-2.0.3.0` which does offer support to `RL9.1` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

CIFS filesystem is not supported by your system:

**Install the `cifs-utils`**

For Rocky Linux 9, remove and install

`dnf remove cifs-utils`

`dnf install cifs-utils`

With yum:

`yum -y install cifs-utils`

For Debian

`apt-get install cifs-utils`

**Maybe you will need the `smbclient` too**

For Rocky Linux 9

`dnf install smbclient`

With yum:

`yum -y install smbclient`

For Debian

`apt-get install smbclient`

**Samba install:**

`dnf install samba samba-common samba-client`

`yum install samba samba-common samba-client`

**Disable the dummy module:**

Maybe you need to try to disable the dummy module, edit and add to the end of file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

`blacklist DUMMY_MODULE_NAME`

Reboot your system to apply the changes and after rebooting, check if cifs support is enabled and functioning correctly on your system.

**Try enable cify manually on your system:**

Identify the kernel module for cifs

`modprobe --list-modules | grep cifs`

than load cifs manually as su

`modprobe cifs`

Other Sources:

[Nvidia OFED stack disables cifs mounts](https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/nvidia-ofed-stack-disables-cifs-mounts/9638)

[How do I prevent a kernel module from loading automatically?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/41278)

[RockyLinux: unable to load cifs module](https://serverfault.com/questions/1089770/rockylinux-unable-to-load-cifs-module)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already installed `cifs-utils` and all of the `samba` pacakges. I have tried reinstalling them too but unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: I have trouble understanding this answer: it tells to disable the cifs module (which IS the dummy module) and then to miraculously hope it can be enabled again and working.

Comment: No disable the dummy module then check if it is deactivated and check if cifs-utils works if not try to enable cifs manually

Comment: blacklisting `cifs` and then loading it manually will load the same module if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: and modprobe has no option `--list-modules` for me